# Can we have two buildkite CI/CD pipelines for a single github repo?

Tags: design-patterns, cicd, buildkite

The reason for two separate pipelines for a single GitHub Repo is that two pipelines are responsible for deploying to two different AWS accounts (due to legacy reasons, we need to have one piece of code to run in two production environments).

I have looked into the buildkite documentation, but it seems it is not possible. I am aware that I can put the development steps to two AWS accounts into one buildkite pipeline, but I felt it is good to separate them for clarity.

Let me know if separating them is not a good design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment is a step in a CICD pipeline. So weather to deploy in 1 environment or 2 is just a step level config. You don't have to (should not) create 2 separate pipelines to achieve what you wish.

Have 2 separate steps with 2 different queues (1 agent in each account with unique queue name) to deploy. These steps can be sequential or parallel. Can pass data or values or could be totally independent.